# “Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working” error while running a plugin project in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, java-8, eclipse-plugin

I have made a plugin project in Eclipse Kepler. But when I run that plugin either in kepler or luna or as an eclipse application, It randomly crashes in between and exits saying "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working" .

- Java Version 1.8.0_25
- JVM 64 Bit
- Windows 10
- Eclipse: Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers(kepler)
- swt 64 bit

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in your question to allow us to help you.  It could be a bug in your plugin, a bug in eclipse, a bug in Java, a broken installation, a broken dependency ... a hardware problem ...

Comment: what is ur exact problem?

Comment: If this is a JVM problem you should try running a much newer version of Java 8 - update 144 is current.

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version sounds like a good plan, running on Windows 10 isn't supported in 1.8.0_25: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html

Comment: Thanx @Klara . It worked

Comment: Thanx @greg-449

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading java version to java1.8.0_155 worked for me.